# data.table frollmean very slow

Tags: r, data.table, mean, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate the rolling mean of a column in a large data.table (~30M rows) aggregated by two other columns.
The rolling mean should include only the preceding N row values, not the row value itself. 
For this purpose, i had to define my own rolling mean function based on frollmean function. (N=3)
Applying the function to the column is really really slow, rendering it rather useless.

Here is sample data:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C')
               , value_type =c('type 1', 'type 1','type 2','type 1','type 2','type 2','type 1','type 1','type 2','type 1','type 1','type 1')
               , value=c(1,4,7,2,3,5,1,6,8,2,2,3))
    DT
         ID value_type value
     1:  A     type 1     1
     2:  A     type 1     4
     3:  A     type 2     7
     4:  A     type 1     2
     5:  A     type 2     3
     6:  A     type 2     5
     7:  B     type 1     1
     8:  B     type 1     6
     9:  B     type 2     8
    10:  C     type 1     2
    11:  C     type 1     2
    12:  C     type 1     3

#this is the customised rolling function
lrollmean<-function(x){

  head(frollmean(c(NA,NA,NA,x), n = 3, fill = NA, algo ="exact", align="right", na.rm = TRUE)[-(1:2)], -1)

}

> DT[, roll_mean := lrollmean(value), by=.(ID, value_type)]
> DT
    ID value_type value roll_mean
 1:  A     type 1     1       NaN
 2:  A     type 1     4       1.0
 3:  A     type 2     7       NaN
 4:  A     type 1     2       2.5
 5:  A     type 2     3       7.0
 6:  A     type 2     5       5.0
 7:  B     type 1     1       NaN
 8:  B     type 1     6       1.0
 9:  B     type 2     8       NaN
10:  C     type 1     2       NaN
11:  C     type 1     2       2.0
12:  C     type 1     3       2.0
```

This operation takes more than 30 minutes! I've got a reasonable machine which ample RAM, and I feel the long time of the operation has something to do with my code rather than the machine.

Comment: do you have a large number of groups? for e.g. out of the 30M rows, how many groups are there? and do you really need `algo="exact"`?

Comment: data has about 800,000 unique IDs. and no, i don't believe i really need algo = "exact" :)

Comment: i changed algo="exact" to algo="fast" and it was much much faster!

Comment: If you would really need exact, then switching to 1 thread may help in case there are many groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try and see if its fast enough:

```
n <- 3L
DT[, roll_mean := {
        v <- if (.N - n >= 1L) c(seq.int(n), rep(n, .N-n)) else seq.int(min(n, .N))
        shift(frollmean(value, v, adaptive=TRUE))
    }, .(ID, value_type)]
```

But if you have a large number of small groups, you can try:

```
setorder(DT[, rn := .I], ID, value_type)
rid <- DT[, rowid(ID, value_type)]

DT[, roll_mean := shift(frollmean(value, n))]

ix <- DT[rid==3L, which=TRUE]
set(DT, ix, "roll_mean", DT[, shift(frollmean(value, n - 1L))][ix])

ix <- DT[rid==2L, which=TRUE]
set(DT, ix, "roll_mean", DT[, shift(value)][ix])

DT[rid==1L, roll_mean := NA_real_]
setorder(DT, rn)[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. To compare, i tried the first solution on my data set and i get this error Error in rep(k, .N - k) : invalid 'times' argument. also, while we're at it, seeing as I over-simplified my problem for the post, there are actually two columns by which the mean should be calculated. ID and another column called, value_type. Could your solution be catered to include two aggregating columns, or is it really bad practice to do that? many thanks

Comment: can you update your dataset so that there is no ambiguity?

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12  I've edited my post to match my real dataset, with added value_type in the data.table. The k is the same as n in your code. I had to use k in my code instead of n to not get it mixed up with another variable. I don't think the error is in syntax as I tried using n and i get the same error.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira, updated the code to address the error when there are less than 3 rows and when adding one more grouping variable

Comment: Thanks so much @chinsoon12   . at the moment i'm investigating this error i get while trying the first solution:                                   Error in froll(fun = "mean", x = x, n = n, fill = fill, algo = algo, align = align,  : 
  length of integer vector(s) provided as list to 'n' argument must be equal to number of observations provided in 'x'.

Comment: i think i am missing the equality sign. have amended as such

Comment: thanks so much @chinsoon12. The first solution is 10% faster, and the second one is much faster. the only issue is that for both solutions the rollmean of second and third entries are still missing. I'll see if i can improve the second solution to get exactly what I want. I've marked your response as the solution since it's 98% there. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: oh i added rid==3L and rid==2L to address that. can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `frollapply` and  since `frollmean` doesn't completely suit your needs. You can also optimize the function you apply to the window, since you don't need a very complicated operation. I've tried a few modifications to your function that should cut your time down by around 50%.

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
N=1e6
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(ID=stri_rand_strings(N,3),
                 value=rnorm(N,5,5))
head(DT)
#>     ID      value
#> 1: HmP 12.2667538
#> 2: sw2 -2.2397053
#> 3: WtY  7.0911933
#> 4: SxS  0.4029431
#> 5: gZ6  8.6800795
#> 6: tF2  0.8228594
DT[,.(.N),by=ID][order(N)]
#>          ID  N
#>      1: HoR  1
#>      2: eNM  1
#>      3: I9h  1
#>      4: xjb  1
#>      5: eFH  1
#>     ---       
#> 234823: 34Y 15
#> 234824: Xcm 15
#> 234825: IOu 15
#> 234826: tob 16
#> 234827: f70 16

# Your function
lrollmean<-function(x){ 
  head(frollmean(c(NA,NA,NA,x), n = 3, fill = NA, algo ="exact", align="right", na.rm = TRUE)[-(1:2)], -1)
}

#Possible modifications:
lrollmean1<-function(x,n){
  frollapply(c(rep(NA,n),x),n+1,weighted.mean,c(rep(1,n),0),na.rm=T)[-(1:3)]
}
lrollmean2<-function(x,n){
  frollapply(c(rep(NA,n),x),n+1,function(x) sum(x*c(rep(1,n),0)/n,na.rm = T))[-(1:3)]
}
lrollmean3<-function(x){ # More optimized assuming n=3
  frollapply(c(NA,NA,NA,x),4,function(x) sum(x[1:3]/3,na.rm = T))[-(1:3)]
}


library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(original={DT[, roll_mean := lrollmean1(value,3), by=.(ID)]},
          a={DT[, roll_mean := lrollmean1(value,3), by=.(ID)]},
          b={DT[, roll_mean := lrollmean2(value,3), by=.(ID)]},
          c={DT[, roll_mean := lrollmean3(value), by=.(ID)]}
          ,replications = 1,order = 'relative')
#>       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
#> 4        c            1   6.740    1.000     6.829    0.000          0
#> 3        b            1   8.038    1.193     8.085    0.012          0
#> 1 original            1  13.599    2.018    13.692    0.000          0
#> 2        a            1  14.180    2.104    14.233    0.008          0
#>   sys.child
#> 4         0
#> 3         0
#> 1         0
#> 2         0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>